# jquery plugin works on localhost but not on server: "Object [object Object] has no method 'slippry'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I stripped everything down to just the plugin and put it on a random old test site: 
[Demo](http://cuddlefish.site11.com/demo/)

This is the main part of the code and the links are correct.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slippry.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#slideshow").slippry({
                transition: 'fade',
                useCSS: true,
                speed: 2000,
                pause: 6000,
                auto: true,
                preload: 'visible'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The common issues of wrong links or two instances of jquery being called can't be the problem. It's been driving me crazy.

Comment: Your site appears to work, only the slippry CSS style file is missing so they appear one under the other. What browser are you getting the error on?

Comment: The slippery CSS is included at the top of my page. I get the error on Google chrome but it seems that all modern browsers aren't giving me the correct output.

Comment: The stats plugin from your hosting company is loading jquery 1.5.2 within j.js. Maybe there is a conflict?

Comment: That could be it! Gah damn you free hosting! I'll load it somewhere else to test that theory.

Comment: The pieces of your page work fine in a JSFiddle, so it is most likely a version clash with your hosting.

Comment: Just tested it on a different server and it works. Geezer68 and TrueBlueAussie thank you for your help!